# Best Practices for Random Enemy Animations?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, animation-controller

For various animations for NPCs (getting hit with projectiles, shooting, dying) I've been creating 2-4 animations each in blender before exporting. Should I be doing this inside Unity with Animation Controllers instead? Either way what would be the best practices to actually randomizing the animations?